# How to increase the limit for GCM subscription topic

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, publish-subscribe

I'm using the GCM subscribe topic and found it's very interesting and easy to use.

However, according to my understanding from Google that there's a limit of 1 million subscriptions per app. My app have about 100+ topics and 200K of users, if each user subscribe 5 topics, it will be not enough for my case.

I couldn't find anywhere on Google Developer website to change this limit or how to manage it. The only option they recommend is unsubscribe the device which is like asking the user to uninstall my app.

I'm scratching my head for many days and still couldn't find an ideal solution for it. I really appreciated for your time and help.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no workaround for this scenario.

Comment: One idea that comes to mind is to create multiple topics (xxx1, xxx2, xxx3, ...) and when you want to subscribe to topic 'xxx', the app choose one of the actual topics.  When you want to send a message to topic 'xxx', the server sends a copy to xxx1, xxx2, xxx3, etc.  Not ideal but it might work.

Comment: @EugeneStyer this won't work because GCM limits the number of subscriptions per app, not per topic.

Comment: Try my idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435926/gcm-topics-or-downstream-messaging

Answer (score 0):

It no longer has a limit.

> We’re now happy to announce that we’re allowing unlimited free topics
>   for your app. This means app developers can place an unlimited number
>   of devices within each topic and create an unlimited number of topics.

[Source](https://developers.googleblog.com/2015/12/google-cloud-messaging-weve-come-long.html)