# Sending to GCM topics

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Probably a GCM newbie question...

I more or less understand how to subscribe to topics and how to send messages to topics. But I was wondering : how does a topic gets created ?

From the docs I read, I guess a topic exists when at least one app subscribes to it, correct ? (As far as I could see there's no specific api to 'create' a topic).

I also noticed that it should be possible to register apps to a topic not from the app itself, but from an app server (by sending a `HTTP POST` message to a specific `URL`). Does this work the same way ?

E.g. if the topic doesn't exist when subscribing, it will be 'created'?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, yes, whatever topic name a client app uses when subscribing, will get created. Even if it is "sdfgklfhjashfgkjas" and purely accidental.

I have seen no mention of deleting topics. I guess unused topics don't really cause Google any problems; they don't take up much space.

On the server side, you can force an app instance to subscribe to a topic by passing the token in a http POST [as mentioned in the GCM documentation](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server). Ditto for unsubscribing from a topic.

Bear in mind [there are limits on topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435926/gcm-topics-or-downstream-messaging) which could cause problems for popular apps.

Answer (score 0):

**How does a topic gets created?**

There is no detailed explanation in the documentation on how topics are created but according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/api/gcm/interface_g_c_m_pub_sub).

> An app can subscribe to different topics defined by the developer. The app server can then send messages to the subscribed devices without having to maintain topic-subscribers mapping. Topics do not need to be explicitly created before subscribing or publishing—they are automatically created when publishing or subscribing.

**From the docs I read, I guess a topic exists when at least one app subscribes to it, correct ?**

I think this is the case because in order to create a topic you will have an app subscribe to it.

**I also noticed that it should be possible to register apps to a topic not from the app itself, but from an app server (by sending a HTTP POST message to a specific URL). Does this work the same way?**

Yes your app can subscribe to other topics not necessarily related to your app as long as you pass the GCM registration token and topic name. See [Subscribe to a topic](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging#subscribe-to-a-topic).